# how can match packet content dynamically in snort?

Tags: dynamic, packets, snort

I want to check a keyword with packet content in snort but not a static word.

I want it be dynamic for example get this keyword form terminal in ubuntu.

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:" your content found"; sid:100000; content:"something to find"; )
```

That codes are used for static value.

Share your ideas please.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some examples of content you want to match? There's no way to do "dynamic" words with content match, but you can use pcre.

Comment: what can i do with pcre???  content to match can be any word. i mean i want to get a word from terminal and search for it in packet content and show the result of search with a message in terminal. tnx

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you provide some sort of example?

Comment: imagine cin>>x; in c++ i want to do this in snort. i don't want to enter word to check for match in rule like above code i want to ask the user which keyword you want to search? and then get this keyword from user and search for that.   thank you for your quick answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only way to accomplish something like this would be to use a shared object rule. I do not believe there is any way to do it otherwise.  Shared object rules are one of the more difficult things to implement in snort rules but it would certainly be possible to do something like this with it.  I recommend reading [this blog post](http://blog.snort.org/2011/02/snort-shared-object-rules.html) about how to use shared object rules.

Answer (score 0):

What about a wrapper script that accepts rule by console, write it to a rule file, and then reloads snort?